# Laravel : Conditional select columns using Elequent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get columns with some if conditions like "if column is null, get other column instead".

My current code

```
$products = Product::whereHas('images', function($q) {
    $q->where('published', 1)
})->get(['id as value', 'product_short_name as label']);
```

Need to make it like

if `prdouct_short_name` is `Null` get me `product_name` as `label`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL you can try to use rawSelect.

```
Product::whereHas('images', function($q) {
    $q->where('published', 1)
})->selectRaw('id as value, IF (product_short_name IS NULL, product_name, product_short_name) as label')->get();
```